# How to create installer for java application using visual studio

Tags: java, visual-studio, installation

Hi I have create a sample java application and created a jar file. Now I want to create installer for windows application using visual studio.

How to create windows installer for java application using visual studio.
Also I want my installer should check jre version. and my application should start on boot up of the machine.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Installer XML (WiX) toolkit is an excellent (and very flexible) way of building installers. It's not language specific - you can build installers for anything you like.

http://wix.sourceforge.net/

There are various VS.NET integration addin (Votive being one of them) that will assist in creating WiX files.

If you're serious about creating installers I'd recommend reading up on WiX.

Answer (score 0):

Create new Setup project. And point VS to your files. Actually the only difference between your and ,lets say, c# project is that VS automatically adds C#(VB and so on) output to installer. And you have to do this manually.

About checking JRE version on other things... It looks like you need to an [create custom
action](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/visual-studio-setup---projects-and-custom-actions/)

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)

Easy configuration, just invoke batch in ANT/VC/etc..:

> ISCC.exe yourConfig.iss

This will create You an installer.
Creating shortcuts (desktop, quicklaunch, uninstallers, and more) are very easy.